# Get value(s) in jQuery MultiSelect dropdown?

Tags: jquery, return-value, multi-select

I found this jQuery code which is easy to use, but I can't find a way to get the selected value. I am using Control 7, and would like to have a button beside that `onClick` show the values there are selected in the multi-dropdown.

http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/multiSelect/demo/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the checkboxes in the div next to the element you are interested in and map their values to an array:

```
var values = $("#control_7").next().find(":checked").map( function() { return this.value; });
```

Comment: This work great. I forgot it return it values in a array.Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to do this:
`$("#idofinputfield").val()` and it will return you an array that you could loop over.

Comment: You should be able to, but the plugin doesn't support that.  It replaces the `select` element entirely with a custom control.

Answer (score 0):

You can select inputs that are checked using the `:checked` selector. Check out [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/).

Here is a more complete answer:

```
var valueOfSelected = $('input:checked').attr('name');
$('showNextToInput').html('valueOfSelected');
```

Wrap that in a function and use it in the callback method (like example 6 in the demo you provided).